# fire js/jquery after ajax request is made

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi I have am making an ajax call after my htmlpage is loaded

```
<body onload="init_myfunc();">
<div class="left searchtop" id="suggestionbox" align="center">
-----------------------
```

and my init_myfunc() is ...

```
function init_myfunc(lenletters)
{
  if (typeof lenletters =='undefined' ) {
    var search = '{{q_url}}';
    var query = search.split('?q=')[1];
    query = query.split('&')[0];
    var loc = search.split('&amp')[1];
    loc = loc.split('=')[1];
    var search_val = $("#autosuggest").val();
    requestData = {};
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
      requestData['rec_searches'] = localStorage.getItem('saved_searches');
    }
    requestData['page'] = 'searchboxlong'
    requestData['spellcheck'] = query;
    if(loc!= 'all')
      requestData['location'] = loc;

    $.get('/college-search/autosuggest/', requestData, function(data){$('#suggestionbox').html(data);});

   //$("#autosuggest").val(query); -- This is not working

  }
}
```

Now I want to call this piece of code after ajax call is done

```
$("#autosuggest").val(query);
```

I tried writing it below my ajax call but its not working. As soon as the ajax loads... the text box become empty

Is their a way to set the value of text box after ajax call is done

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in the success callback.

```
 $.get(
     '/college-search/autosuggest/',
     requestData,
     function(data){
         $('#suggestionbox').html(data); 
         $("#autosuggest").val(query);
     }
 );
```